# Convert PowerPoint to Word with MathyType equations

Tags: ms-word, powerpoint

I have a large collection of PowerPoint files that contain floating text boxes and MathType equations that I need to convert to a Word document for editing and publication. Using any of PowerPoints built in conversions losses most of the floating textboxes and all of the MathType equations.

Is there any automated way to achieve this conversion to Word with everything intact, and not transformed into images?

The only decent solution I have come across is saving the PowerPoint as an .rtf outline but that loses all equations and floating boxes.

I'm using PowerPoint 2010 and Windows 7. Though any operating system with a solution I can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer -- no, not "out of the box".

Longer answer is that it *may be* possible with a little work. You don't specify what OS you're using, nor what version of PPT. [On this page is a VBA script](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Convert-PowerPoint-c3a26165) that is supposed to work on PPT 2010. I tried it in PPT 2010 with 2 different presentations, both of which had MathType equations and one of which also had a diagram. In both cases, it converted only slides that were text-only. Slides with any non-text items (diagram and equations) did not convert. If you're a VBA guru, you may be able to look at the VBA and tweak it so that it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not constrained really by an OS and I am using 2010. I was hoping to avoid working directly with any VBA. But given the lack of responses to my question and your answer, I assume there is no simple method out there. Which is was I thought would be the case.